# Content not showing inside .vue file

Tags: vue.js

I have a `Index.vue` file and it has the following contents, but this content is not showing.

```
<div>
  test
</div>

<script>
  export default {
    //
  }
</script>
```

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed the `template` tag

```
<template>
 <div>
  test
 </div>
</template>
```